# How do you set placeholders in python when there are syntax-identical non-placeholders in the text that should be formatted?

Tags: python

I have a HTML template file with some JavaScript and some Python placeholders e.g.`{foobar}` that i want to replace by a script.

To replate these placeholders i load the content of the file by:

```
file = open("template.html", "r")
content = file.read()
file.close()
foobars = {
    "foobar_1": "bla",
}
content = content.format(**foobars)
```

My problem is that in the JavaScript code some placeholder-like formatting exists like `google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});` so that i get a `KeyError: "'packages'"`.

### Question

How do you set placeholders in python when there are syntax-identical non-placeholders in the text that should be formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your templates, double any braces that don't delimit format placeholders:

```
google.charts.load('current', {{'packages':['corechart']}});
```

`str.format` will convert double braces to single braces instead of treating them as format placeholders.

If you can't do this, you're basically screwed. Your input format was badly designed, and you're paying the price.